# unity3d 5.0 C# getting error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity 5.0, I get the following error because of the code I wrote below. Unfortunately, I don't get it, can anyone help please ?

> moneyGet.cs(19,17): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `moneySystem.money'

```
using UnityEngine;

public class moneyGet : MonoBehaviour
{
    int curHealth = 100;

    int maxHealth = 100;

    public void Update()
    {
        if ( curHealth > maxHealth )
        {
            curHealth = maxHealth;
        }

        if ( curHealth < 0 )
        {
            curHealth = 0;

            moneySystem.money += 100;//name of your script moneySystem
        }

    }
}
```

However, the following code doesn't throw any error :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class moneySystem : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public int money = 0;//amout of your money

    GUIText moneyText;//To Display Your money    

    void Update()
    {
        if ( money < 0 )
        {
            money = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Partially off-topic, but this is where code standards come in handy... C# tends to define classes with camel casing and capital letters where the variables start with lower casing..

Comment: Personally, I hate when people down-vote without justification.  As for partially off-topic, disregard.  You have a legitimate question, and while learning, everybody has their own coding style and naming conventions.  Unity is weird in that you don't know which order the objects are created, and then the "components" added to the game objects too.  I too am learning in  the process.

Comment: @DRapp - My downvote wasn't linked to my comment. It was linked to the fact that if you [google "An object reference is required to access non-static member"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=An+object+reference+is+required+to+access+non-static+member&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=7JwSVfOgL4ae7gah1YGoAg) you get flooded with duplicates with answers

Comment: @DRapp I think the convention comment is particularly good as if conventions were to be followed it would be immediately obvious that OP is referencing the class `moneySystem` statically instead of an instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

Or, depending on your intended context of the game's duration, you could make your moneySystem class a STATIC class so it is always available for entire game duration without "loosing" object reference... make the properties on it static too.

```
public static class moneySystem : MonoBehaviour {

   public static int money = 0;//amout of your money

   GUIText static moneyText;//To Display Your money
   ... rest of class...
```

Then if you had other elements, game scenes, etc, you would not have to worry about trying to instantiate them and oops forgot, or by reinstantiating them loose any previous "money" values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Unity so I can't comment on the overall design, but like the compiler tells you, you need a reference to `moneySystem`, as its `money` peroperty isn't static.

So you can instantiate a `moneySystem` in `moneyGet`'s constructor:

```
public class moneyGet
{
    private moneySystem _moneySystem;

    public moneyGet()
    {
        _moneySystem = new moneySystem();
    }
}
```

Then in `Update()` you can do `_moneySystem.money += 100;`.